# How convert "Hi bro" in array ( [H,i, , b,r,o] )?

Tags: arrays, rust, type-conversion

I need to turn a word into an array of characters.
I tried

```
let str = "Hi bro";
let some_str_arr = str.chars().collect::<String>();
```

Comment: Try `let some_str_arr = str.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>();`

Comment: Generally speaking, "*turning a string into an array of characters*" is probably the wrong way to solve your higher level problem.  Very occasionally it might be a correct approach, but if you're new to Rust (and from your profile/question I'm guessing so?) it might be wise elaborating the task you're  actually trying to accomplish in order that better suggestions can be made.

Answer (score 2):

`str.chars()` splits the string per each character. Then if you do `.collect::<String>()` it collects all the characters into a String. Basically you get the same String as you started with.
What you have to do is to collect into a vector.

```
let some_str_arr = str.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

`some_str_arr` will be a `Vec<char>` in this case.

If you need `Vec<String>` instead then you have to convert each characters to String before collect.

```
let some_str_arr = str.chars().map(|c| c.to_string()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```